# How to pass the output of a executable as one of args of another executable in Windows CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd, pipe

As title,

I need to process data in my program,

which those data are needed by an existed executable.

And I want to pass data through pipe instead of writing data as a file.

My platform is Windows 7.

Any one can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a pipe for passing output as an argument to another program. Pipes connect the STDOUT of one process with STDIN of another process.

If you want the output of the first process to be used as an argument for the second process you could do something like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('p1.exe') do set output=!output! %%a

p2.exe "%output%" /foo /bar ...

endlocal
```